# "Live Reload" does not work for SwiftUI code loaded from Swift Package

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swift-package-manager

I have some SwiftUI code that I put inside a Swift Package. Since you can't run SwiftUI code from a Swift Package directly as [this question suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59732075/run-swiftui-preview-from-spm-package) I loaded the Swift Package as an [editable local dependency on a real test xCode project](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-add-local-swift-package-as-dependency/26457/13).

I can get the SwiftUI code from the Swift Package to execute.

However, the live refresh does not work like it should. To get the "Live Preview" to render the SwiftUI code from the Swift Package I have to Clean (shift + command + K) -> Build (shift + command + K) -> Refresh (option + command + P) every-time.

Any thoughts on how I can get "Live Preview" to work with this setup?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run SwiftUI preview from SPM Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59732075/run-swiftui-preview-from-spm-package)

Comment: No, that question does not adequately describe my specific problem. Also, that question is phrased around running just a Swift Package. I'm running an actual xCode project with the Swift Package loaded as an editable dependency.

Comment: I edited the question to illustrate the differences between questions.

Comment: I am encountering the same issue, any solution?